# Use IF statement to return record even if column value is null

Tags: mysql

Hello gurus of Databases.
I have a little problem with my MySQL query where a field can return **NULL**
If it returns NULL, the entire record would not appear even though the record should exist.

The query is:

```
SELECT 
        `job_status_update`.`job_status_id` AS `last_job_status_id`,
        `job_status`.`status_name` AS `last_status_name`,
        `job_report`.`id` AS `job_report_id`,
        `job_report`.`start_time`,
        `job_report`.`form_number`,
        `job_report`.`activity`,
        `job_report`.`end_time`,
        `job_report`.`date_added` AS `reported_date`,
        `job_report`.`omc_site_manager_signature`,
        `omc`.`name` AS `omc`,
        `assigned_job`.`date_added` AS `date_assigned`,
        `job`.`id` AS `job_id`,
        `job_category`.`category_name` AS `job_category_name`,
        `job`.`date_received`,
        `job`.`work_order_number`,
        `job`.`job_description`,
        `job`.`omc_site_name`, `job`.`deadline`,
        `equipment`.`name` AS `equipment_name`,
        `reported_faulty_equipment`.`fault`,
        `reported_faulty_equipment`.`root_cause`,
        `reported_faulty_equipment`.`solution`
FROM `job_report` 
        INNER JOIN `assigned_job` ON `job_report`.`assigned_job_id` = `assigned_job`.`assigned_job_id`
        INNER JOIN `job` ON `assigned_job`.`job_id` = `job`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN `job_status_update` ON `job_status_update`.`job_id` = `assigned_job`.`job_id`
        LEFT JOIN `job_status` ON `job_status_update`.`job_status_id` = `job_status`.`id`
        INNER JOIN `reported_faulty_equipment` ON `reported_faulty_equipment`.`job_report_id` = `job_report`.`id`
        INNER JOIN `equipment` ON `equipment`.`id` = `reported_faulty_equipment`.`equipment_id`
        INNER JOIN `job_category` ON `job`.`job_category_id` = `job_category`.`id`
        INNER JOIN `omc` ON `job`.`omc_id` = `omc`.`id`         
WHERE `job_report`.`id` = 6
        AND `job_status_update`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`job_status_update`.`id`) AS `last_job_status_update` FROM `job_status_update`)
```

I realized that the offending part of the query lies in the WHERE clause.

```
AND `job_status_update`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`job_status_update`.`id`) AS `last_job_status_update` FROM `job_status_update`)
```

because `job_status_update`.`id` can be `NULL` hence the query would not return a row if the "job" does not have a "job status update".

Please how do I return the records even if `job_status_update`.`id` is NULL?
I have seen examples of using the `IF...ELSE` statement. But I am not able to make any headway.

`EXPLAIN` output:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   PRIMARY     job_report  const   PRIMARY,assigned_job_id,fk_Job_Report_Job_Report_1  PRIMARY     4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY     assigned_job    const   PRIMARY,job_id,fk_Assigned_Jobs_Job_1   PRIMARY     4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY     job     const   PRIMARY,fk_Job_Job_Category_2,fk_Job_Omc_id     PRIMARY     4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY     job_status_update   const   PRIMARY,job_id  PRIMARY     4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY     job_status  const   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY     job_category    const   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY     omc     const   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   const   1   
1   PRIMARY     reported_faulty_equipment   ref     job_report_id,fk_Faulted_Equipment_Job_Report_1,eq...   job_report_id   4   const   2   
1   PRIMARY     equipment   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   resl_v2.reported_faulty_equipment.equipment_id  1   
2   SUBQUERY    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Select tables optimized away
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to return rows if `job_status_update.id` is `NULL` and `MAX(job_status_update.id)` is also `NULL` - correct? If so, this is the syntax in MySQL:

```
AND job_status_update.id <=> (SELECT MAX(job_status_update.id) ...)
```

The `<=>` operator works like `=`, except that `NULL <=> NULL` returns `1`.

Some time ago I wrote an article on how to write `NULL` comparisons in SQL. I don't want to spam, but since it's related to your question, you may find it useful: [NULL comparisons in MariaDB, PostgreSQL, and SQLite](https://vettabase.com/blog/null-comparisons-in-mariadb-postgresql-and-sqlite/). Note that MariaDB works exactly like MySQL in this respect.

Comment: You are not spamming - you are expanding on your answer by pointing to an article you **clearly** state that you wrote! This is fine - and +1 for the article!

Comment: @federico-razzoli

Thanks for the eye opener with regards to your article. 

Finally, I modified the WHERE clause into 

        WHERE job_report.id = 6 AND NOT (job_status_update.id <=> (SELECT MAX(job_status_update.id) AS last_job_status_update FROM job_status_update))
        
        GROUP BY reported_faulty_equipment.id;

It works! but I have to use the GROUP BY clause because of duplicate row being returned (due to the join).

Thanks once again. 

Please, if there is any tip on how get the unique rows returned, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Esnest Elikem glad to hear that. Using GROUP BY is fine if you want to set a uniqueness constraint on a set of columns. If you want to have it on all columns, you may prefer SELECT DISTINCT. The results and the performance will be exactly the same, but I find it more practical.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option appears to be to move the offending condition from `WHERE` to the `ON` clause of the `job_status_update` join definition, so that instead of

```
…
        LEFT JOIN `job_status_update` ON `job_status_update`.`job_id` = `assigned_job`.`job_id`
…
WHERE `job_report`.`id` = 6
        AND `job_status_update`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`job_status_update`.`id`)
                                               AS `last_job_status_update`
                                        FROM `job_status_update`)
```

you would end up with

```
…
        LEFT JOIN `job_status_update` ON `job_status_update`.`job_id` = `assigned_job`.`job_id`
          AND `job_status_update`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`job_status_update`.`id`)
                                                 AS `last_job_status_update`
                                          FROM `job_status_update`)
…
WHERE `job_report`.`id` = 6
```

This way the `` `job_status_update`.`id` `` filter would apply only to the `job_status_update` table and not the whole join result set.

Note that aliasing the `MAX` column is unnecessary in this case, so you can also write

```
…
        LEFT JOIN `job_status_update` ON `job_status_update`.`job_id` = `assigned_job`.`job_id`
          AND `job_status_update`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`job_status_update`.`id`)
                                          FROM `job_status_update`)
…
WHERE `job_report`.`id` = 6
```

At the very list, this way your output rows would not be eliminated because of the null returned by the `MAX` subquery, though at the same time I am not entirely sure that the subquery would work the way you expect.  The subquery would just return the last `id` value from `job_status_update` without any further qualifications, and I have a sneaking suspicion that you actually want the last `id` *for a given `job_id`*.  If that is the case, you could further modify the joining condition like this:

```
…
        LEFT JOIN `job_status_update` ON
          `job_status_update`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(`job_status_update`.`id`)
                                      FROM `job_status_update`
                                      WHERE `job_status_update`.`job_id` = `assigned_job`.`job_id`)
…
```

But of course I might be wrong, in which case please ignore that last suggestion.